# A general form of a circle throw common points of two circles

Tags: analytic-geometry

We have two non intersecting in $\mathbb R^2$ circles:
$
C_1(x,y)\equiv x^2+y^2-2mx-2ny+p=0,
$
$
C_2\equiv x^2+y^2-2m'x-2n'y+p'=0,
$
where circles are with real coefficients and positive radiuses.
Then they intersects in some $(a,b), (a',b')\in \mathbb C^2$.
Let $C$ be an arbitrary circle, with or without real points, with real coefficients, passing throw $(a,b), (a',b')$.
I wish to know, is $C$ is the form  $\alpha C_1(x,y)+\beta C_2(x,y)$, for some real $\alpha, \beta$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES

Given
$$C_1:x^2+y^2-2mx-2ny+p=0;\;C_2:x^2+y^2-2m'x-2n'y+p'=0$$
The linear combination

$$\mathcal{C}:\lambda C_1+\mu C_2=0$$
$\mathcal{C}$ gives the family of all circles, real or complex, passing through the intersection points of the two given circles.

For the special values $\lambda=1;\;\mu=-1$ we get the equation of the line joining the intersection points $(a,b), (a',b')$ wich is perpendicular to the line containing all the centers of $\mathcal{C}$

$(2m'+2m)x+(2n'-2n)y+p-p'=0$

Comment: Maybe references to $$\mathcal{C}:\lambda C_1+\mu C_2=0$$
 gives the family of all circles, real or complex, passing through the intersection points of the two given circles.

Comment: $\lambda C_1+\mu C_2=0$ passes through the intersection points because $C_1=0;\;C_2=0$ implies $\lambda\cdot 0+\mu\cdot 0=0$

Comment: Yes, but why if $C$ passes by the intersetion's points of two circles, then it has to be a linear combination of their equations.

Comment: because the intersection points satisfy both $C_1=0$ and $C_2=0$, thus any linear combination of the two

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a circle is

- quadratic,
- with equal coefficients of the squares, $x^2$ and $y^2$,
- without mixed term $xy$.

Now the combination $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2$ is

- quadratic,
- with equal coefficients of the squares, $x^2$ and $y^2$,
- without mixed term $xy$

hence it is the equation of a circle.

Plus, any point that belongs to *both* circles satisfies $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2=0$ and also belongs to that circle. So if the two given circles make two intersections, the whole family shares these intersections.

---

Notice that the coefficients of the squares can vanish, leaving the equation of a straight line as a degenerate case. For the same reason as below, this is the line through the two intersection points.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why $C$ passing by $(a,b), (a',b')$ is of the form $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2=0$.

Comment: @Alex: $(e^{C_1})^\alpha(e^{C_2})^\beta=1$ would also work.

Comment: I understand that $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2=0$ is a circle (or a complex straight line), and this circle contains $(a,b), (a',b')$ but I don't understand  why $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2=0$ is equivant $C(x,y)=0$.

Comment: @Alex: $\alpha\,0+\beta\,0=0$.